# Как убедить PyCharm не ругаться на мой метод?

Tags: python, ооп

У меня в программе есть метод:

```
    def import_config(self, flag=None):
        """Функция 'посредник', между GUI и 'config_generate', работает в двух режимах, в зависимости от передаваемого
        флага. В режиме импорта забирает словарь, сгенерированный 'config_generate' и заполняет 'lineEdit's напротив
        'label's. А в режиме экспорта считывает с 'lineEdit's данные, формирует из них словарь и отдает его в
        'config_generate'."""

        dict_imp = config_generate()

        list_of_lines = sorted([x for x in dir(ui) if "lineEdit" in x], key=lambda x: int(x.split("_")[-1]))
        list_of_labels = sorted([x for x in dir(ui) if "label" in x], key=lambda x: int(x.split("_")[-1]))
        list_of_labels.remove('label_2')

        lst_eval_labels = list(eval("(self." + ", self.".join(list_of_labels) + ")"))
        lst_eval_lines = list(eval("(self." + ", self.".join(list_of_lines) + ")"))

        if flag != 'export':
            for x in range(0, 49):
                lst_eval_lines[x].setText(dict_imp[lst_eval_labels[x].text().rstrip()])
        else:
            values = []
            text_of_labels = []
            for x in range(len(lst_eval_labels)):
                text_of_labels.append(lst_eval_labels[x].text().rstrip())
            for x in lst_eval_lines:
                values.append(x.text())
            config_generate(dict(zip(text_of_labels, values)))
```

Ему не нравится, что это метод, а не функция: `"Method 'import_config' may be 'static'"`. Либо же он предлагает сделать его статическим. Если вы знакомы с методом `eval()`, то вы сразу поймете в чем тут загвоздка. Я не могу пойти не на первый вариант, не на второй. Может быть у вас есть мысли, как решить проблему?

Comment: Вопрос года!)))

Comment: Про тело вопроса я молчу, вроде всё как обычно. Вот сам вопрос вызывает улыбку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ругается PyCharm в данном примере из-за того, что функция является методом, но не использует преимуществ метода. другими словами ключевое слово `self` нигде не используется. если хотите, вы можете выключить этот `warning`. наведите курсор на имя функции и нажмите `Alt` + `Enter`, в всплывающем окне будут варианты решения вопроса, где один из них будет `Disable Inspection`.

Comment: В том то и дело, что self используется, но неявно

Comment: а как по вашему `pycharm` отловит использование `self` в строке?))

Comment: Ну понятное дело, что никак) Ну не суть) Вот что имеется в решениях проблемы) https://gyazo.com/8310b6910c41684374508f936de66e64

Comment: Disable Inspection не вижу там

Comment: ну я вам вроде предложил вариант, мне кажется, что это единственный выход

Comment: Странновато, что нет заглушки варнинга

Comment: вообще исключения пайчарма странная штука. по хорошему бы просто поставить более боейвой линтер, но мне всегда было лень.

Comment: А все, разобрался, спасибо